# Is it possible to make only one thread run with GDB

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, gdb

I'm learning how to use GDB to debug multi threading C++11 program.

Here is my test code:

```
void func()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << ": " << (i++) <<std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(func);
    std::thread t2(func);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Well, this is quite simple: two infinite loops, each of them is executed by a thread.

I execute `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -g -lpthread` and get a binary file `a.out`.

After running `a.out` on the terminal A, I open another terminal B to attach on it with `gdb`: `gdb -p <PID_of_a.out>`.

Now the output of `a.out` on the terminal A is stopped as expected.

Then, I execute `info thread` on the terminal B:

```
(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id         Frame
* 1    Thread 0x7f3b10c24740 (LWP 62395) "a.out" 0x00007f3b10803d2d in __GI___pthread_timedjoin_ex (threadid=139891642771200, thread_return=0x0, abstime=0x0,
    block=<optimized out>) at pthread_join_common.c:89
  2    Thread 0x7f3b0faca700 (LWP 62396) "a.out" 0x00007f3b1080cc70 in __GI___nanosleep (requested_time=0x7f3b0fac9d90, remaining=0x7f3b0fac9d90)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nanosleep.c:28
  3    Thread 0x7f3b0f2c9700 (LWP 62397) "a.out" 0x00007f3b1080cc70 in __GI___nanosleep (requested_time=0x7f3b0f2c8d90, remaining=0x7f3b0f2c8d90)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nanosleep.c:28
```

So thread 1 is the main function, thread 2 and thread 3 are the two threads of `func`.

Then I execute `thread 2` to switch to the thread 2.

Now, I keep typing `n` to make the thread 2 run.

What I want to do is to make the thread 2 run while making the thread 3 keep stopping. However, it seems that thread 3 is executed too because of typing `n` on the thread 2. Here is the output of the terminal A:

```
139891642771200: 17
139891634378496: 17
139891642771200: 18
139891634378496: 18
139891642771200: 19
139891634378496: 19
139891634378496: 20
139891634378496: 21
139891634378496: 22
139891634378496: 23
139891642771200: 20
139891634378496: 24
139891634378496: 25
```

You can see the last third line: `139891642771200: 20`, it comes from the thread 3.

So my question is if it is possible to make only one thread run with GDB? If possible, what could I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For stepping through the program (`step`, `next`) GDB supports locking the scheduler to the current thread:

```
set scheduler-locking step
```

Of course stepping like this will only work if the thread is able to make progress (i.e. no locks held by other threads, etc.)

As far as I know, no such possibility exists for *running* the program (`run`, `continue`, `finish`).

Comment: Hi dude, after reading your answer, I just google the `scheduler-locking` and tested `set scheduler-locking on`, it seems that this is what I need.

Comment: I switch to the thread 2 and execute `set scheduler-locking on`. And then I keep typing `n`, now there isn't any output from thread 3.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need `thread 2 run while making the thread 3 keep stopping`?

If just want break at thread 2, you could use [Thread-Specific Breakpoints].(https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Thread_002dSpecific-Breakpoints.html)

Comment: Because I may need to debug some cases, such as a dead lock issue. In these cases, making some specific thread run may be helpful.